# Rails 4 - ActiveAdmin layout is blank but application layout works for custom controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a Rails4 app with `active_admin` for admins only.i have been using it for quite a long time and has customised it to the way i want and it has always worked but now , it is this little weird issue which i am unable to resolve.

**My observation---**
my layout has `active_admin.html.erb` and `application.html.erb`.When i rename my active_admin.html.erb or delete it..the custom action works and renders properly but other pages shows up double content rendering containing of two headers,body and footers, but when i keep the admin layout everything works, but the custom action renders blank layout.

i have a custom action in my controller block inside my `admin/hall.rb` model, which is also getting executed as per the server logs which also includes the active_admin layout too BUT on the screen , **i cannot see any layout and its just blank but when i use application layout explicitly in the controller block, it works.**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Hall do

controller do


  ##explicitly add helper to be used by existing partials 
  helper ApplicationHelper 
  ###DO NOT WORK
  #layout 'active_admin' # <-- here
  ##THE WEIRD PART################
  layout 'application' , :except => [:activities] ===> this render the application layout perfectly which i dont want , as i need the active_admin layout
  layout 'active_admin' , :except => [:activities]  ==> also render the application layout...STRANGE
  layout 'active_admin' , :only => [:activities]  ==> render the application layout but with only icon and entire page is blank


  def activities
    @hall = MODEL.find params[:id]
    @activities = @hall.get_public_activity
    ##EVERYTHING BELOW THIS DO NOT WORK, I HAVE TRIED IT
    #render :activities, :layout => false
    #render :partial=>'admin/halls/activities', :layout => "active_admin"
    ##render "activities", layout: "active_admin"

  end 




       #######server logs
    Processing by Admin::HallsController#activities as HTML
    ...
    ...
    ....

       (1.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."trackable_id" = $1 AND ("activities"."owner_id" IS NOT NULL)  [["trackable_id", 1021]]
      PublicActivity::Activity Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."trackable_id" = $1 AND ("activities"."owner_id" IS NOT NULL)  ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0  [["trackable_id", 1021]]
      User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
      Announcement Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "announcements".* FROM "announcements" WHERE "announcements"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1021]]
      Rendered public_activity/announcement/_create.html.erb (19.4ms)
      Rendered admin/halls/activities.html.erb within layouts/active_admin (27.4ms)
     ...
     ...

    Completed 200 OK in 681ms (Views: 368.8ms | ActiveRecord: 56.4ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms)
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what is going wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now i know what was the reason.Looking through the logs clearly mentioned something about the layout and when i searched the code, i founded out that there was a code to override the BaseController of ActiveAdmin.i removed that code now and now its working the way i want.i am sharing the code below that was causing the problem...

```
###admin/custom_layout.rb
###XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX    REMOVED THIS FILE ###########################
# module BaseControllerPatch
#   def determine_active_admin_layout
#     ##'activeadmin_custom_layout/application'
#     'active_admin'
#   end
# end

# module ActiveAdmin
#   class BaseController
#     prepend BaseControllerPatch
#   end
# end
```

Now i dont have any cusotm active_adin code and by default,its working perfectly without any need to add custom code.However, i want to add custom attributes in the body tag, which i can easily add in `initializers/active_admin.rb`

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

By default ActiveAdmin bypasses Rails ActionView layouts in favor of its own Views::Pages components built in Arbre.  Hence the active_admin.html.arb in ActiveAdmin contains

```
insert_tag view_factory.layout
```

and you are not expected to override it. ActiveAdmin does not use application.html.erb, which makes me think you may be using the Active Admin Custom Layout gem. Can you confirm that, and also whether you are using an ActiveAdmin version from RubyGems or the latest from GitHub?  Custom pages in Active Admin are in fact the only ones that use ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Layout which then does call ActionView's content_for_layout: a potential source of much confusion, and probably the cause of the inconsistent behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks @Piers C,  ActiceAdmin from Rubygems and the one from GitHub are the same...that's what I think...kindly correct me if I am wrong.i am using gem directly specifying it in the Gemfile.what should I do?Do you need more details so that you can help me out.

Comment: After looking into my Gemfile...this is what I found -.                 gem 'activeadmin', git: 'https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git'    and that's all I have it in my Gemfile.I am not using     gem 'activeadmin_custom_layout'

Comment: Ok, you are using 2.0.alpha from GitHub and no custom layout gem. In that case you should not define your own active_admin.html.erb and not specify layouts in your controller. I am not clear what customization you had implemented and are trying to preserve.